# Библиотека для работы с shockwave flash (.swf) файлами - C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

Добрый день! Пришлось работать с .swf файлами. Т.е с flash-анимацией. Да-да, в 2017 году. Понятия не имею какую библиотеку использовать для запуска таких файлов. Гугл наткнул на ShockwaveFlashObjects от самой Adobe (как я понял). Как работать с ним - не знаю. В гугле примеры для Windows forms. Можно ли использовать обычный WebBrowser для работы с .swf файлами и какие в этом минусы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю flash поставляется на целевую систему в нескольких видах. Встроен в браузер (например chrome), в виде отдельного расширения (firefox) и как activex компонент (windows и их проводники) который как раз вам и нужен.

Встроить этот компонент в ваше wpf приложение можно двумя способами, это как вы указали через WebBrowser и тут есть ряд проблем (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607427/run-flash-in-wpf), а также встроить напрямую activex компонент на форму wpf приложения как описано тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/148373/